# Пропадает возможность писать текст в консоли, после изменения фокуса окна

Tags: c#, windows, консоль, .net-core

Имеется консольное .net core приложение. Программа начинается со строк:

```
Console.Write("Укажите путь к файлу CSV: ");
string pathToCSV = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ", "");
```

Когда появляется консоль для ввода текста, пропадает возможность писать что либо в этом окне. Бывает, что сразу не получается ничего написать, а бывает, что сначала писать можно, но затем когда я переключаюсь на другое окно (например проводника) и возвращаюсь снова к вводу текста, возможность писать пропадает.

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: с каким-то другим кодом который сюда не был скопирован? Или же с виндой, если проблема не репродьюсится на других компьютерах

Comment: @Andrew это прям начало метода Main. А ещё такое чудесное свойство заметил: Если открыть экранную клавиатуру и все манипуляции проводить на ней, то всё работает в порядке.

Comment: ищи проблему не в коде,  а в винде или железе. :)

Comment: @Grundy тоже, что и при вводе: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

Comment: Также я предполагаю, что такой эффект ловится только при отладке. Если я просто запускаю dll через powershell или cmd, то всё окей

Comment: @alladuh, в этом случае не сработала ли случайно точка остановки? в этом случае действительно нельзя будет ввести символы

Comment: @Grundy Не, я их все убрал, всё равно так. Попробовал этот проект в vs code, полёт нормальный. Для меня это какие-то чудеса прям

Comment: @alladuh, проверь само окно студии когда перестанет вводиться, на нем в title добавится debugging. Пока это наиболее вероятная причина.

Comment: @Grundy к сожалению на нём Running

Comment: @alladuh, тогда можно только гадать :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за отзывчивость. По моему мнению проблема была в Caramba Switcher (https://caramba-switcher.com/). Суть состояла в том, что он как-то очень быстро менял раскладку клавиатуры или забирал фокус на себя, в общем это приводило к данной проблеме. Я его отключил и проблема исчезла.

Comment: @alladuh, тогда стоит добавить свой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за отзывчивость!
По моему мнению проблема была в Caramba Switcher (https://caramba-switcher.com/). Суть состояла в том, что он как-то очень быстро менял раскладку клавиатуры или забирал фокус на себя, в общем это приводило к данной проблеме. 
Я его отключил и проблема исчезла